# Recover data from SM-N900 - Heimdall/Odin help

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3, odin, heimdall

I have a SM-N900 (Note 3 Exynos), the password for which is forgotten![1], but there is data that need to be recovered.

I am trying to flash TWRP, or CWM recovery image so that I can at least get
to ADB. So far I have tried using **Heimdall**(built from `HEAD` with `libusb-1.0.0-dev` on Ubuntu 14.04), **Odin**(3.9, 3.10 on Windows 10), and none of them seem to be working.

With Heimdall, I get:

```
ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
RECOVERY upload failed!
```

(for which there are a lot of hits on google, but no clear solutions)

And, with Odin, I get:

```
Complete(Write) operation failed.
```

Which also seems to be a fairly common error!

I have tried both USB2.0 and USB3.0 ports (on Windows Odin seems to only recognize 2.0).
I am using the original USB cable which came with the phone.
On Windows, I have Samsung USB drivers installed and Kies/Switch is not installed.

[1]:

- ADM didn't work, somehow, and there seems to be option to use google login (after the last update that happened [must be Lollipop])
- Had not registered with Samsung recovery :(
- USB debugging was not enabled!
- Had not installed CWM/TWRP :(

Answer (score 0):

After burning midnight oil (5 hours straight!), finally I could get **Odin** to flash **TWRP**! I had to do 2 things:

- Not use the `.tar` directly, but extract the `.img` and then use a `.bat` script (found on XDA forums) to convert it to `.tar.md5`
- Get the latest version of the TWRP recovery: `twrp-2.8.6.0-ha3g`

(But I'm not very sure why the original `.tar` didnt work, though!)

Odin version used: `3.10.7`